# How to Remove the Instructions Text in word?

Tags: c#

How to Remove the Instructions Text in word ?

I strucked from the morning. please anyone help me. here is my code.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc1 = app.ActiveDocument;
Selection wordSelection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;
wordSelection.HomeKey(WdUnits.wdStory);

doc1.Content.Find.ClearFormatting();
doc1.Content.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
doc1.Content.Find.set_Style(doc1.Styles["Instructions"]);
doc1.Content.Find.Text = "";
doc1.Content.Find.Replacement.Text = "";
doc1.Content.Find.Forward = true;

bInstructions = doc1.Content.Find.Execute(WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
```

Comment: Try to replace `doc1.Content.Find.Text = "";` with  `doc1.Content.Find.Text = "*";`

Comment: Exactly what happens - are exceptions thrown - if so where & what is the exception?

Comment: @S.Petrosov: For that to work Find.MatchWildcards needs setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a Find object based on the Selection object :

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection wordSelection = app.ActiveWindow.Selection;
    wordSelection.HomeKey(WdUnits.wdStory);
    Find fnd = wordSelection.Find;

    fnd.ClearFormatting();
    fnd.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
    fnd.Forward = true;
    fnd.Wrap = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
    fnd.Text = "";
    fnd.Replacement.Text = "";
    fnd.set_Style("Instructions");
    fnd.Execute(Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
```

Note that the signature for the Execute command is :

```
bool Execute(
ref Object FindText, ref Object MatchCase, ref Object MatchWholeWord,
ref Object MatchWildcards, ref Object MatchSoundsLike, ref Object MatchAllWordForms, ref Object Forward, ref Object Wrap, ref Object Format,
ref Object ReplaceWith, ref Object Replace, ref Object MatchKashida,
ref Object MatchDiacritics, ref Object MatchAlefHamza, ref Object MatchControl)
```

with default values of Missing for each - in your code you were passing WdReplace.wdReplaceAll as the FindText parameter, rather than passing multiple Missing parameters my code uses the named parameter option. Even with the named parameter your code did not do the replacement, so I used the Selection of the current document.